# Return names() of list in lapply() UDF for T-Test

Tags: r

I am trying to pass a list of dataframes through a UDF function for a t-test with `lapply()`. I'd like to print/preserve the argument name (df name) so that I know which test belongs to which df.

```
list <- list(arousSelf = arousSelf, arousOther = arousOther)
ttest <- function(data) {
        d <- t.test(data$pre, data$post, paired = T)
        cohend <- cohen.d(data$pre, data$post, paired = T)
        print(substitute(data))
        print(d)
        print(cohend)
}
ttest(arousSelf)
lapply(names(list, ttest)
```

When I run the function for one df (i.e., arousSelf), `print(substitute(data))` prints the actual argument's name. When I run the list through `lapply()`, numbers are printed instead. I have tried suggestions from different posts but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At least you are missing a ``)`` in your last line of code after ``list``. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point in printing out the objects in the inner function. You'll be printing them anyways when you call it through `lapply`. I would do this...

```
ttest <- function(data) {
    d <- t.test(data$pre, data$post, paired = T)
    cohend <- cohen.d(data$pre, data$post, paired = T)
    list(d, cohend)
}

lapply(lt, ttest)
```